# How do I use twice a devanych/yii2-cart

Tags: php, yii2, cart

hi guys  I have a cart and wishlist in my project. I used devanych/yii2-cart for part of cart and I need such else for wishlist. my question is How do I make wishlist with devanych/yii2-cart?

Comment: Did you try to follow ["supporting multiple shopping carts to same website"](https://github.com/devanych/yii2-cart#supporting-multiple-shopping-carts-to-same-website) section of readme of that library?

Comment: no I didn't try yet, but I wil try it thank you